# Fix drop-down menu CSS style without star hack

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, margin, padding

I have drop-down menu which work properly but there is a problem with CSS style. If I have there on the top CSS file:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Everything is allright. But if I removed this block, I will get this result http://jsfiddle.net/BERRF/8/. How can I fix that to look like as before with star's block? Answer into jsfiddle would be best. Thanks advance.

Comment: _like as before with star's block?_ or without _star's block?_

Comment: as before with star's block but without star's block if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is universal selector. which applies css styling to all the elements.

In your case, you need `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` only to the `ul` and `h3` elements present in the `#accordian` element.

So, use `#accordian ul` instead of using `*`.

```
#accordian ul, #accordian h3{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**JS fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BERRF/11/)

Comment: Thanks but there is still some bottom margin. See original menu http://jsfiddle.net/BERRF/10/